# Why array treated as object when using ngFor

Tags: angular

I have object that contain array:

```
output = {
    columns: [
      { column_name: `No. Transaksi`, data_type: `transaction_number` },
      { column_name: `Tanggal Keluar`, data_type: `transaction_date` },
      { column_name: `Jam Keluar`, data_type: `transaction_time` },
      { column_name: `Jumlah`, data_type: `total` },
    ]
}
```

When I am using ngFor to iterate those item on columns, it caused error `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'`. I am confused why the property is treated as object.

I outputed the property like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let column of output.columns">{{ column.column_name }}</div>
```

In the last version of the app, it is work fine. But now i got this error. How can i solve that?

Comment: Have you checked if `output.columns` gets reassigned anywhere? That's where I would start looking.

Comment: @Cobus I would start with providing a [mcve] reproducing the issue instead :)

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this so that your problem will get cleared

Comment: I check this code in a newly created project which is working fine.  So as @CobusKruger said value for output object must be getting modified somewhere.

Comment: @trichetriche I agree a complete example will be useful, but if the problem can be fixed far quicker than such an example can be constructed if it is what I think it is.

Comment: use normals quotes: " or ', not ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Writ output as

```
output = [{
    columns: [
      { column_name: `No. Transaksi`, data_type: `transaction_number` },
      { column_name: `Tanggal Keluar`, data_type: `transaction_date` },
      { column_name: `Jam Keluar`, data_type: `transaction_time` },
      { column_name: `Jumlah`, data_type: `total` },
    ]
}]
```

Since ngFor only works for arrays, enclose output with [] so it becomes an Object array